# Set AutoLayout width constraint on top-level UIView of custom XIB from Interface Builder or code?

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, interface-builder

How do you set a width constraint on the top-level view of a custom XIB?

This would be `Content View` in the image below.

Clicking the `Add New Constraints` button doesn't let you specify a width. The option is disabled (along with other options).

Is this possible from Interface Builder? If not, is this possible from code? If not, that might explain some layout issues ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Auto-layout sets the `.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to **`true`** on the top-level view loaded from a custom XIB.

You want to set the `.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to **`false`** via code when you load and use that view.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible from Interface Builder?

No. If you have a fixed size to give the view, then set its Size metric to Freeform and give it that size, directly.

> If not, is this possible from code?

Yes, of course. You must have, somewhere, some code that loads the nib, obtains the view, and puts the view into the interface. At that point it is up to you to size and position it, and you can certainly use autolayout to do so, though no law requires that you do it that way; you could just give it a frame and leave things at that, or if the size coming from the nib is right, then you can leave it alone and just position the view with its frame origin or center.